# How I can get the values of the event zoom and change it from an input

Tags: javascript, jquery, zooming, jquery-events

The scenario of my case it's this:

I use this library:

http://fengyuanchen.github.io/cropper/

And as I can see I can use the event zoom to retrieve the values of zoom image. So I want to know how I can get it and change it from an input like selectable or something like this.

```
var $content = $(c_s),
    $image = $(p_s),
    $dataWidth = $(i_w_s),
    $dataHeight = $(i_h_s),
    $dataX = $(i_x_s),
    $dataY = $(i_y_s),
    options = {
        autoCropArea: 1,
        strict: true,
        guides: true,
        highlight: true,
        dragCrop: false,
        cropBoxMovable: false,
        cropBoxResizable: false,
        movable: true,
        background: true,
        minContainerWidth: 340,
        minContainerHeight: 226,
        minCanvasWidth: 340,
        minCanvasHeight:226,
        minCropBoxWidth: 340,
        minCropBoxHeight:226,
        aspectRatio: radio,
        crop: function (data) {
            $dataX.val(Math.round(data.x));
            $dataY.val(Math.round(data.y));
            $dataHeight.val(Math.round(data.height));
            $dataWidth.val(Math.round(data.width));
        }
    };

$image.on({
  'zoom.cropper': function (e) {
    console.log(e.type, e.ratio);
  }
}).cropper(options);
```

This is a documentation of this library
https://github.com/fengyuanchen/cropper#zoomcropper

In end of the code as you can see I have a `console.log` to check if there is something, but there is nothing in my Firebug console.

Answer (score 0):

**Documentation**

```
$().on('zoom.cropper', function (e) {
  var maxRatio = 10;
  var imageData = $(this).cropper('getImageData');
  var currentRatio = imageData.width / imageData.naturalWidth;

  // Zoom in
  if (e.ratio > 0 && currentRatio > maxRatio) {

    // Prevent zoom in
    e.preventDefault();

    // Fit the max zoom ratio
    $(this).cropper('setCanvasData', {
      width: imageData.naturalWidth * maxRatio
    });
  }

  // Zoom out
  // ...
});
```

*Your code*

```
$image.on({
  'zoom.cropper': function (e) {
    console.log(e.type, e.ratio);
  }
}).cropper(options);
```

See the difference.. the syntax

It should be

```
$image.cropper(options);
$image.on('zoom.cropper', function (e) {
    console.log("Here "+e);
})
```

Comment: Hi vinayakj, 

Thanks for you comment, I try to do it like you show it but i doesn't work. I use the first code because i get it from the example demo site.

http://fengyuanchen.github.io/cropper/

If you try to zoom while viewsing the console on firebug you can discover the console shows you the zoom event, and if you inspect the code you can find the code and i think it's maybe in the case you want to use more than 1 event.

Comment: You can find here https://github.com/fengyuanchen/cropper/blob/master/demo/js/main.js, line 38 =)

Comment: Try the updated code please, and can you create a jsFiddle if it wont work